# Lightning Component - Second Level of an Associative Arrays are not accessible from Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

We have a component which was working fine, until Yesterday - we are using Associative arrays. So I created a simple component and replicated the issue.

Component

```
<aura:component controller="LightningAdminController">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

    <aura:attribute name="data" type="Object"/>

    <div>Value: {!v.data.obj.key}</div>
    <div>UserId: {!v.data.user.Id}</div>

</aura:component>
```

Controller

```
({
  doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
    var data = {
      'obj': {
        'key': 'Valuess'
      }
    };
    component.set('v.data', data);
    console.log('data: ', data);
    helper.getLearner(component);

  }
})
```

Helper

```
({
  getLearner: function(component) {
    var self = this;
    var action = component.get("c.UserDetails");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
      var state = response.getState();
      if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
        var data = component.get("v.data");
        data.user = response.getReturnValue();

        component.set("v.data", data);

        console.log('UserID: ', component.get("v.data").user.Id);
      }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
  },
})
```

I can see the UserID in the console log, but the component doesn't show the user ID, it stays blank. Any suggestions.

Thanks.

**Edit:**
If I add the key - user (with value UserID) to the data in controller it works fine, I mean the v.data.user.Id shows 'UserID' and then it is replaced with the one from the Action call.

Controller

```
({   doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
    var data = {
      'obj': {
        'key': 'Valuess'
      },
      'user': {
        Id: 'UserID'
      }
    };
    component.set('v.data', data);
    console.log('data: ', data);
    helper.getLearner(component);

  } })
```

Comment: I've another observation that we have getters & setters for every key that is there in an associative array, but we dont have those when we add a new Key.

Comment: I don't know if this will improve the situation, but you may as well set the attribute type to "Map" rather than "Object". In any case it does seem that right now under Locker it sets up bindings the first time you push an object to a view attribute and/or the first time you get the value of the object using `component.get`. But then it doesn't necessarily refresh those bindings when the schema changes.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. No "Map" dint work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can re-create the Object/Map and set to the component, not perfect but it will work for now until the Locker bindings are fixed.